# How to pass a string to base hierarchy header class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to do a custom controller that inherits from "Controller" class and add other headers and methods to use it as Controller for all the controllers in my project.

This is my code

```
namespace Filters
{
    [Localization("en")]
    public abstract class CustomController : Controller
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();
        private Log log;

        protected Log initLog(string aController)
        {
            this.log = new Log(aController, SG.getUser(Session), VG.config_string_connect_log);
            return this.log;
        }

        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            TempData["MensajeExcepcion"] = filterContext.Exception.Message;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "Error500",
                TempData = TempData
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What i dont know how to do is, when i inherit from CustomController, how to specify, the language for use it in **[Localization("es")]** for example. In this case is "en", but, could i specify in the moment that i inherit, another string ?

i was thinking maybe with a generic Type, but... the header is before... :(

**public class MyController : CustomController<¿Something?>() {
}**

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a base controller class with a property that you´ll override in the child controllers. See below:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public abstract string Localization { get; }
}

public class MyController1 : BaseController
{
    public override string Localization => "en";
}
```

Does this approach work for you?

Comment: i thnk no, cause that will be just a BaseController properti :(

Answer (score 0):

But that will be just a BaseController string properti, how to use it in the Localization definition in the header ?

*namespace Filters

{

[Localization("en")]  **<---- HERE**
public abstract class BaseController : Controller

{